# Exchange should serve public .com address but is connected to .local Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

From previous advice I've created my Domain Controller (2008R2) with a mydomain.local name (instead of mydomain.com, split DNS scenario)
So my users have logins like admin@mydomain.local. And for logging in to the servers that fine I guess.

Now on the Same domain I've installed a Exchange 2010 server. (with client access External domain pointing to our public mydomain.com) 
After install I see that my domain admin is imported and has its own mailbox. When I look at the details I see for email: admin@mydomain.local.

Of course this makes sense but its not what I'm looking for. The mailserver should be serving the public .com domain and it would be nice if users can enter with their .com adres and credentials.

So the question is can I configure this and where should I do this to make it work for all new users I import from AD.

For the record I'm still in a test environment. In their I've created forward lookup zone for mydomain.com so I'm able to test all public domain stuff offline before I migrate.

Comment: There's no such thing as PDC/BDC any more. A Domain Controller can hold the PDC Emulator FSMO role, but it's not the same as being a PDC from the NT4 days.

Comment: Thanks not sure what you mean but I meant with PDC my Primary Domain Controller I will rephrase my question

Comment: There are no primary domain controllers any more. There haven't been since Windows 2000 Server was released. All DCs are multi-master peers.

Comment: By the way. You shouldn't use .local if you can help it. To avoid split-horizon DNS situations use a non-public third-level domain for your AD. Example: ad.mydomain.com.

Comment: Hi MD Thanks, this one is a bit difficult for me. I didn't use the Split brain because of all the configurations needed. And sub domain (I know MS advises this one) I didn't choose because in our situation we can have the domain fully local and don't need the domain name later for any public stuff. And to be honest it looked the easiest and I got a lot of different advices from people. Looks like a lot of people choose there strategy based on a number of different reason.
So it looks like the correct strategy is the one that fits your situation bests.. So I thought I choose the right one.

Comment: There's no reason to use .local when you have a perfectly usable sub-domain. Even if it's never going to be public (which your AD shouldn't be) you should still use a third level subdomain. What happens if ICANN starts selling .local TLDs? It's not reserved or anything. By using .local you're ignoring relevant RFCs and standards. Also, you'll make any OS X workstations on your network grumpy since .local is used in mDNS

Comment: Ok before I will build the real domain I will read-up more about the pro's and con's of .local versus sub domain. We are building a cloud network with only servers no clients but still I will think about it again. Thanks for all your thoughts on the matter! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to this you need to hash out:

1) You will need to add the .com domain in Exchange setup as a domain that it is responsible for and set up the policies and whatnot to distribute those as the primary sending domain for your users.

2) Somewhere in one of the AD snap-ins, I cannot remember if it's domains and trusts or users and computers, you can define additional user principle names, so that your users can login as user@domain.com OR user@domain.local. You can then specify the primary per user.

Just keep in mind, the mail handling of domains and the user login handling of domains is each a different animal.

Comment: Ok thanks for the ideas I will first try to read up on the pointers you gave me and report back if I have problems.

Comment: See this article [Configure Exchange 2010 to Accept E-Mail for More Than One Authoritative Domain](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996314.aspx)

Comment: @Zoredache thanks that helps. Already found: http://exchangeserverpro.com/change-business-email-domain going to read them both and try it out

Comment: It is in fact in Active Directory Domains and Trusts where you add additional UPN suffixes.

Comment: Ok changed the accepted domain and edited default email policy to include the new domain so now all mails are updated. Not sure if it all works but I'll test that later.

Ah nice tip Joe! Ok I will go and find that UPN stuff now.

Comment: Addin UPN suffix was easy to. Ok now I'm going to test a lot of stuff. Thanks all.

Comment: It would behoove you to condition your users NOW to login with their username@domain.com that way it's consistent across computer login, outlook web access, and whatnot.